# How to POST via Reddit API (addcomment)

Tags: php, curl, reddit

I've been able to successfully log a user in and return their details. The next step is to get them to post a comment via my app.

I tried modifying code from the reddit-php-sdk -- https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk/blob/master/reddit.php -- but I can't get it to work.

My code is as follows:

```
function addComment($name, $text, $token){
    $response = null;
    if ($name && $text){
        $urlComment = "https://ssl.reddit.com/api/comment";
        $postData = sprintf("thing_id=%s&text=%s",
                            $name,
                            $text);
        $response = runCurl($urlComment, $token, $postData);
    }
    return $response;
}

function runCurl($url, $token, $postVals = null, $headers = null, $auth = false){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $auth_mode = 'oauth';

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
    );

    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer {$token}");
    $options[CURLOPT_HEADER] = false;
    $options[CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT] = false;
    $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
        $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    if ($postVals != null){
        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postVals;
        $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = "POST";
    }

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $apiResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($apiResponse);

    //check if non-valid JSON is returned
    if ($error = json_last_error()){
        $response = $apiResponse;    
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$thing_id = 't2_'; // Not the actual thing id
$perma_id = '2daoej'; // Not the actual perma id

$name = $thing_id . $perma_id;
$text = "test text";

$reddit_access_token = $_SESSION['reddit_access_token'] // This is set after login

addComment($name, $text, $reddit_access_token);
```

The addComment function puts the comment together according to their API -- http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

addComment then calls runCurl to make the request. My guess is that the curl request is messed up because I'm not receiving any response whatsoever. I'm not getting any errors so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The reddit SDK you linked already provides that capability. I suggest you just use the SDK and forget about trying to homebrew your own solution. This way you don't have to worry about maintaining the SDK as long as you update it periodically.

Comment: My issue is that I coded the oAuth login/token retrieval without using the SDK and it works perfectly and I don't want to figure out how to do it again on the SDK. All I really did (or tried to do) was hard code in the access token where it belongs in the SDK since I don't get it via the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own oAuth solution, I would suggest using the SDK as I said in my comment, but extend it to overwrite the construct method.

```
class MyReddit extends reddit {
    public function __construct()
    {
        //set API endpoint
        $this->apiHost = ENDPOINT_OAUTH;
    }
    public function setAuthVars($accessToken, $tokenType)
    {
        $this->access_token = $accessToken;
        $this->token_type = $tokenType;

        //set auth mode for requests
        $this->auth_mode = 'oauth';
    }
}
```

You just need to **make sure** that you call `setAuthVars` before running any api calls.

Comment: I get stuck in a redirect loop like with the other guy's answer.

Comment: I had the config file set up wrong causing the redirects. Either way, this doesn't seem to use the access token I try to give it. It sends me to log in then it sends me to the specified redirect page without posting anything. My code is `require_once("reddit-sdk.php");
    $MyReddit = new MyReddit();
    $authvars = $MyReddit->setAuthVars($reddit_access_token, 'Bearer');
    $response = $MyReddit->addComment($name, $text);`